# Git: Mirror single file from one repository into another

Tags: git, continuous-integration, repository, mirror

Let's say I have two repositories and a parameter file in repository A. The same file is needed for repository B and should be updated with git pull in repository B if there was an update in repository A on this file. The other way (from B to A) is not needed.

Is there a simple way to mirror a single file from a repository into another and keep it up to date?
Solutions could also make use of CI pipelines!

Any ideas to face this?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simple way to mirror a single file from a repository into another and keep it up to date?

*Simple* is perhaps in the eye of the beholder.  I suspect that for your case, the answer is no, but perhaps you'll think of the following as simple after all.

The key item to remember here is that Git doesn't store *files*.  Git stores *commits*.  The commits then store files, but it's a package deal: every commit has a full snapshot of *every* file.  You either have a commit—and therefore *all* the files—or you don't have the commit, and thus none of the files.

This means that if you want to deal with a single file, instead of a whole collection of files, you have several choices:

- Use different *commits* in repositories A and B.  The commits in A have lots of files including this parameter file.  The commits in B have lots of files including this parameter file.

  This gives you two sub-options in B:

  - B has all the commits that A has, plus B-specific commits that only B bothers with, and whenever there's a new commit in A you get it (the entire commit) and then build, in B, a new B-specific commit that takes a recent B-specific commit and swaps out this one file for a new file and then commits the result.
  - Or, B doesn't have all the commits from A.  Instead, when there's an update to this file in A, you have some software that (1) notices; then (2) generates a new B-specific commit by extracting some existing B-specific commit, updating the file in place, and making a new B-specific commit.

  You should note that these two sub-options are mostly the *same thing:* the difference is whether repository B just automatically includes all commits from repository A (something Git is very good at: Git *loves* to add commits to its collection), or not.  The software that creates a new B-specific commit needs some way to discover when A has a new commit that has a different version of the file in question, and having all the A commits locally within B makes that easy, but makes the B repository "fatter".
- Or—this is where things get a little tricky—consider isolating the parameter file to *its own* repository, C.  Now repositories A and B can both clone C.  When there is a new parameter file, you add it to repository C and commit.  Repositories A and B fetch and update their clones of C, which get them the latest parameter file.

  This is the simplest method by far, mechanically.  It may have some other mechanical issues though: perhaps the *name* of the parameter file can't be changed easily.  If your OS offers symbolic links (or equivalent), you could make the "parameter file" in A and B be a symlink to where they will hold their clone of C with its parameter file.  Or, you can use a complicated trick as in the next overall option.
- There's a hybrid variant of this "third repository" method.  The drawback with this hybrid variant is that it makes generating and committing new parameter files more difficult, and a simple `git checkout` also doesn't work in *either* of the two repositories A and B: instead, you need a special "checkout then update" sequence.  (But CI systems tend to be pretty good at doing special work like this.)

  Here, instead of committing the parameter file as a regular "all files, including parameter file" commit, you make parameter-file commits that, as commits, contain only the one parameter file.  So far, this is exactly like having the third C repository.

  What makes this a hybrid, though, is that instead of a third *repository*, you just have this file on its own "orphan branch" in both repositories A and B.  That is, instead of:

  ```
  git checkout main
  # now you have all files including the parameter file
  ```

  you'll run:

  ```
  rm paramfile                   # it's untracked: now it's gone
  git checkout paramfile-branch
  # now you have only one file: the parameter file, paramfile
  ```

  You can now update the file and commit.  Then you go back to your main branch (or any other branch) and there's no parameter file here, so now you *extract* the parameter file *from* the `paramfile-branch`:

  ```
  git show paramfile-branch:paramfile > paramfile  # or similar
  ```

  Your `.gitignore` file in this branch lists `paramfile` as ignored (there's no `.gitignore` file in the commits on `paramfile-branch` at all: there, it's a *tracked* file, and also the *only* file) so this is just a temporary file, as far as *Git* is concerned.

  Since the file is only ever updated *in* repo A, repo B can fetch from repo A's `paramfile-branch`, writing the resulting hash ID into repo B's `paramfile-branch` name:

  ```
  git fetch repo-A +paramfile-branch:paramfile-branch
  ```

  to pick up new commits from this branch.

This last method is just a way of embedding "repo C" inside both repositories A and B, using a single branch name (`paramfile-branch`) to hold the hash ID of the last commit in "repo C" (as embedded into A and B).